# Error using parallel processing with snow in bootMer on glmmTMB object

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lme4, statistics-bootstrap, glmmtmb

I am encountering an error while attempting to use parallel processing with the "snow" argument in the `bootMer()` function on a `glmmTMB` object in R. I followed the suggestions provided in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015036/13000254), but the issue remains unresolved. Here's a reproducible example:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(glue)
require(lme4)
require(parallel) # to parallelise bootstrap step
require(glmmTMB)

m1 <- glmmTMB(count ~ DOY + mined + (1|site), 
              family = nbinom2, data = Salamanders)
summary(m1)

pred_data1 <- data.frame(mined = c("yes", "no")) %>% 
  group_by(mined) %>% 
  reframe(DOY = unique(Salamanders$DOY)) %>% 
  # NA column required for random effect
  mutate(site = NA)

pred_fun <- function(model) {
  predict(m1, newdata = pred_data1, type = "link", re.form = NA, 
          allow.new.levels = TRUE)
}

par_cores <- max(1, floor(detectCores()/2))
par_cluster <- makeCluster(rep("localhost", par_cores), outfile = "log.txt")
clusterEvalQ(par_cluster, library("glmmTMB"))
clusterExport(par_cluster, varlist = c("Salamanders"))

print(glue("Using {par_cores} cores."))

pred_bootMer <- bootMer(m1, nsim = 1, FUN = pred_fun,
                        parallel = "snow",
                        use.u = FALSE, type = "parametric",
                        ncpus = par_cores, cl = par_cluster)

stopCluster(par_cluster)
```

I have tried using `clusterEvalQ(par_cluster, library("glmmTMB"))`, `clusterEvalQ(par_cluster, library(glmmTMB))`, and `clusterEvalQ(par_cluster, {library(lme4); library(glmmTMB)})`, but none of these solutions have resolved the issue. I still encounter the following error:

```
Warning message:
In bootMer(m1, nsim = 1, FUN = pred_fun, parallel = "snow", use.u = FALSE,  :
  some bootstrap runs failed (1/1)
```

Note: in my actual runs, I use 1000 sims, and the message says all 1000 failed. And `pred_bootMer$t` just gives NAs. It's worth noting that the problem occurs specifically when using `parallel = "snow"` and setting `n_cpus` to a value greater than 1, as OP pointed out in the linked question.

Any insights into resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated. Should I consider reopening the [issue](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/843) on GitHub for `glmmTMB`? Additionally, I want to clarify that I am using `bootMer()` rather than `bootstrap_parameters`.

### Edit (16/07/2023)

I fixed the issue with the function being provided to `bootMer`, and also added my original model to the list of objects being exported, but I am still getting the `bootstrap runs failed` message.

```
pred_fun <- function(some_model) {
  predict(some_model, newdata = pred_data1, type = "link", re.form = NA, 
          allow.new.levels = TRUE)
}

par_cores <- max(1, floor(detectCores()/2))
par_cluster <- makeCluster(rep("localhost", par_cores), outfile = "log.txt")
clusterEvalQ(par_cluster, library("glmmTMB"))
clusterExport(par_cluster, varlist = c("Salamanders", "m1"))

print(glue("Using {par_cores} cores."))

pred_bootMer <- bootMer(m1, nsim = 2, FUN = pred_fun,
                        parallel = "snow",
                        use.u = FALSE, type = "parametric",
                        ncpus = 2, cl = par_cluster)

stopCluster(par_cluster)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a typo/thinko.  The function you pass to `bootMer` should reference the model passed to it as an argument, not the original model; substitute `model` for `m1` inside your function:

```r
pred_fun <- function(model) {
  predict(model, newdata = pred_data1, type = "link", re.form = NA, 
          allow.new.levels = TRUE)
}
```

You also need to make sure that you've exported `pred_data1`:

```r
clusterExport(par_cluster, varlist = c("Salamanders", "pred_data1"))
```

If you leave the function as written above and add `m1` to your list of cluster-exported objects, `bootMer` would run but you'd get the same answer in every bootstrap replicate (because it would ignore the resampled data/refitted model and use the original `m1` every time ...)

Although it was previously undocumented (it now is in the *development* version on Github), you can access the error messages via

```r
attr(pred_bootMer, "boot.fail.msgs")
```

For example, if I forgot to export `pred_data1`, I'd get this:

```
object 'pred_data1' not found 
                            2
```

(the 2 is the number of times that error occurred). This will help a lot in debugging future problems!

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed a thinko. However, the bootstrap runs are failing even after your corrections. Please see my edit.

Comment: Another thinko/typo, I think. See edit.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a lot for this. Final question to help me get a more intuitive understanding of the parallelisation: it seems here we don't need to export `m1`. Is this because it is directly provided to `bootMer` instead of being called from within a different function as in the case of `pred_data1`?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  [These lines](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/bootMer.R#L97-L113) make sure that the fitted model (called `x` inside the function) is available to all workers, but there's no way for `bootMer` to know what *other* objects you will want to use in the function you're evaluating ...

Comment: Do you have any clues as to what's going on with this similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77091903/6574038), @BenBolker?