# How to safely export lazy object to workers in function within function?

Tags: r, linux, parallel-processing, lazy-evaluation, lme4

I have a function `f` in a function `g` that first manipulates a call from `lm`, `lme4::lmer` or `lmerTest::lmer` and re-`eval`uates it. `f` will be repeated in `g` `R` times using `vapply` (type 1), or `mclapply` (type 2), `parSapply` (type 3).

```
g <- \(fit, type=1, R=2L, nc=2L) {
  f <- \(...) {  
    ## f manipulates call
    if (inherits(fit, 'lmerMod')) {
      cl <- fit@call
      ## manipulate...
      lme4::fixef(eval(cl, envir=fenv))
    } else {
      cl <- fit$call
      ## manipulate...
      eval(cl, envir=fenv)$coe
    }
  }
  fenv <- new.env()
  environment(f) <- fenv
  if (type == 1) {  ## rep. using `vapply`
    bc <- vapply(seq_len(R), f, numeric(ncol(model.matrix(fit))))
  } else if (type == 2) {  ## rep. using `mclapply`
    bc <- parallel::mclapply(seq_len(R), f, mc.cores=nc) |> do.call(what='cbind')
  } else if (type == 3) {  ## rep. using `parSapply`
    .CL <- parallel::makeCluster(nc)
    on.exit(parallel::stopCluster(.CL))
    parallel::clusterExport(.CL, c('fit'), envir=fenv)
    bc <- parallel::parSapply(.CL, seq_len(R), f)
  } else stop('type undefined')
  return(bc)
}
```

While it always works using `vapply` or `mclapply`, it always fails using `parSapply`. Unfortunately, `parSapply` is exactly what I'm currently depending on. Noted also a difference when using `lm`, `lme4::lmer` or `lmerTest::lmer`. Further I need to provide the formula as objects, which complicates things.

##### So, first the `lm` case.

```
fo1 <- mpg ~ cyl

g(lm(fo1, mtcars), type=1)  ## works
g(lm(fo1, mtcars), type=2)  ## works
#                 [,1]     [,2]
# (Intercept) 37.88458 37.88458
# cyl         -2.87579 -2.87579

g(lm(fo1, mtcars), type=3)  ## fails
# Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
#  2 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'fo1' not found
```

##### Next, the `lme4::lmer/lmerTest::lmer` cases, which fail differently.

```
data('sleepstudy', package='lme4')
sleepstudy$foo <- 0 ## to keep promise
    
fo2 <- Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject)

g(lme4::lmer(fo2, sleepstudy), type=1)  ## works
g(lme4::lmer(fo2, sleepstudy), type=2)  ## works
#                  [,1]      [,2]
# (Intercept) 251.40510 251.40510
# Days         10.46729  10.46729

g(lme4::lmer(fo2, sleepstudy), type=3)  ## fails
# Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
#  2 nodes produced errors; first error: bad 'data': object 'sleepstudy' not 
#  found

g(lmerTest::lmer(fo2, sleepstudy), type=1)  ## works
g(lmerTest::lmer(fo2, sleepstudy), type=2)  ## works
g(lmerTest::lmer(fo2, sleepstudy), type=3)  ## fails
# Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
#  2 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'fo2' not found
```

`lm` and `lmerTest::lmer` agree on that the formula is not found, whereas `lme4::lmer` can't find `sleepstudy`.

##### Finally, the `parSapply` variants when the formula is explicitly specified.

```
g(lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars), type=3)  ## works
#                 [,1]     [,2]
# (Intercept) 37.88458 37.88458
# cyl         -2.87579 -2.87579

g(lmerTest::lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy), type=3)  ## works
#                  [,1]      [,2]
# (Intercept) 251.40510 251.40510
# Days         10.46729  10.46729

g(lme4::lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy), type=3)  ## fails
# Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
#  2 nodes produced errors; first error: bad 'data': object 'sleepstudy' not 
#  found
```

`lme4::lmer` still can't find `sleepstudy`. I played around with the `fenv <- new.env()`, if I don't use it, the only change is, that `lme4::lmer` can't find the formula like the others, but among those no change.

Could use some help getting `parSapply` working with all `lm`, `lme4::lmer` and `lmerTest::lmer`. I suspect some laziness, so not all parts of the `lmer` objects get exported to the workers. Also not sure in which environment they live, already messed around with `envir=parent.frame()` to no avail.

---

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: Europe/Zurich
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] vctrs_0.6.3         nlme_3.1-163        cli_3.6.1           rlang_1.1.1        
 [5] generics_0.1.3      minqa_1.2.5         glue_1.6.2          colorspace_2.1-0   
 [9] lme4_1.1-34         scales_1.2.1        fansi_1.0.4         grid_4.3.1         
[13] lmerTest_3.1-3      munsell_0.5.0       tibble_3.2.1        MASS_7.3-60        
[17] numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 lifecycle_1.0.3     compiler_4.3.1      dplyr_1.1.2        
[21] Rcpp_1.0.11         pkgconfig_2.0.3     rstudioapi_0.15.0   lattice_0.21-8     
[25] nloptr_2.0.3        R6_2.5.1            tidyselect_1.2.0    utf8_1.2.3         
[29] pillar_1.9.0        parallel_4.3.1      splines_4.3.1       magrittr_2.0.3     
[33] Matrix_1.6-1        tools_4.3.1         gtable_0.3.4        matrixStats_1.0.0  
[37] boot_1.3-28.1       ggplot2_3.4.3
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things here:

- the main difference between `mtcars` and `sleepstudy` is that `mtcars` is part of base R, so will be available in any instance of R; it won't need to be loaded.
- I'm not sure why the `lmerTest`  example works: I think it may be because the `lmerTest` package **depends** (in the technical sense) on `lme4`

I'll point out that everything works if we refer to the data as `lme4::sleepstudy` rather than `lme4`.

```r
g(lmerTest::lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), 
   lme4::sleepstudy), type=3)
```

It should also work (although I haven't tested it) if you make sure that `lme4` is loaded on the cluster nodes (e.g. via `parallel::clusterCall(.CL, library, "lme4")`)

To make this work in general you should probably do something like

```r
datanm <- deparse(fit@call$data)
assign(datanm, eval(fit@call$data))
clusterExport(.CL, datanm)
```

(not tested)